# Entering "more than" (>) into a number field - database design

Tags: ms-access, database-design, integer

A client is looking to have a number field in a database that goes from 1 - 10.  However, they would also like the option of "more than 10".  Are there any best practices for adding this to a number field (integer) or is it even possible?

This feels like an inane and simplistic question and I'm hesitant to ask it but searches have revealed nothing and I feel like I may be missing a simple trick.

Comment: Isn't it possible to agree on a number value like -1 to show >10 ?

Comment: Perhaps change your abstraction.  Use two values, representing a range of numbers.  `1,1` would be exactly `1`, but `1,2` would be everything between `1` and `2`.  Then, `10,NULL` would be everything from 10 and over.  This would still be generalised in case of future functional changes.  Alternatively, don't generalise, but instead be specific, treat the value as an enumerator; then, the value 10 can mean 10, and the value 11 mean everything over 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with Access (and most other database applications) anyway. Number fields can only contain valid numbers (or nothing, if NULL is permitted), and neither "more than 10" nor "> 10" is a valid number.

Years ago I did a bit of work with *FileMaker Pro* and I remember it being quite "loose" in what it would allow to be entered into a field of a given "type". The field's "type" seemed to be more of a "suggestion" as to how an entry was to be interpreted. That opened up a certain degree of flexibility (to handle cases such as yours), but it also often left the user vulnerable to whatever assumptions the software made when interpreting a peculiar value.

In any case, "> 10" would have to be handled as a special case, so you'd probably do just as well to make the field a text field and use a combo box to select the values

```
1
2
3
...
9
10
more than 10 (or "> 10")
```

Comment: Gord is correct in that number fields will only accept numbers. So, your options are either make it a text field, or you can have a separate boolean field as a flag meaning more than 10. This would also require extra programming of the user interface.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I like the idea of the -1 denoting more than, but in reality, you can't compare continuous data with a category, so we'll see how the client feels.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the user's selection to a valid value, i.e. a numeric value between 1 and 10 or a value of "more than 10", I would:

Create a lookup table with two fields ID (long), RecValue (text).

The table will have 11 records, where ID will have the values 1 to 11 and RecValue "1","2",..."10","more than 10".

Use a combobox for the data entry:

RowSource=
Bind on the ID field but show only the RecValue field.
Set "Limit to list" property to TRUE.

The user sees text, but behind the scenes you are using a numeric value.